# Python application template

Tags: python, templates, installation, naming-conventions, setup-project

I am creating many Python projects so I'd like to have a base template for them.
I found **Quickly** and **Paster** as tools using templates.

I am using bazaar as VCS (with build-deb plugin) so I'd like to have it initialized on start.

Are there any other tools for creating Python projects templates which creates base file structure with tests, debian dir for buildeb and other needed files?
I need it easy to customize. Or maybe there are existing standard templates?
I have some troubles when starting projects, for example what is the convention, how projects should looks like?! any tutorials/samples for this?

Answer (score 1):

I think framework is quick answer to your question, for example in web there is very mini framework `flask`

Welcome | Flask (A Python Microframework) -> http://flask.pocoo.org/

in flask there is :

- code convention, Pocoo Styleguide — Flask 0.9-dev documentation ->
  http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/styleguide/
- folder example with blueprint Modular Applications with Blueprints —
  Flask 0.9-dev documentation ->
  http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/blueprints/

but there is somethings else like pep8 and ... 
see Python Style Guide -> http://www.python.org/doc/essays/styleguide.html

Comment: I am using Pyramid as web framework, but I need general, lower level tool for any project.

Comment: i think pyramid has some things like Creating a Pyramid Project — The Pyramid Web Application Development Framework v1.3a6 -> http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/project.html

Comment: Yes pyramid uses paster and I don't have problem with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create the file structure of a typical Python project with the help of [PyScaffold](http://pyscaffold.readthedocs.org/). I won't be exactly what you need since it advocates Git as VCS. Another great alternative is [Cookiecutter](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.org/).

Comment: are PyScaffold and CookieCutter still the best current answers in 2020? 
if so why would I use one over the other ?  
I know CookieCutter is generic, so it depends on the template you'd be using, so the question becomes, what's a good template for a general python/library project?